# STM32H723- DMA DAC only works with const only?

Tags: stm32, nucleo, stm32cubeide, stm32h743

In a STM32G4, I was able to setup the DAC DMA such that I could use a regular variable (ie. a `uint8_t` array). However, when I tried porting my code over to an H723, the DAC DMA would not work unless it's with a constant variable (ie. a `const uint8_t` array) that is set before runtime. My application requires runtime changes to the array. A pointer initialization of the array does not seem to work. I was wondering if there is a way to remedy this? Am I stuck with the constant variable? Thank you!

EDIT1: Current Setup of DAC DMA and TIMER

```
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void){
  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
  hdac1.Instance = DAC1;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1) != HAL_OK){
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfig.DAC_SampleAndHold = DAC_SAMPLEANDHOLD_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_T15_TRGO;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_ConnectOnChipPeripheral = DAC_CHIPCONNECT_ENABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_UserTrimming = DAC_TRIMMING_FACTORY;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac1, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Timer15 Config:

```
static void MX_TIM15_Init(void)
{ TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  htim15.Instance = TIM15;
  htim15.Init.Prescaler = 55-1;
  htim15.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim15.Init.Period = 10-1;
  htim15.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim15.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim15.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim15, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

DMA Config:

```
static void MX_DMA_Init(void){
 __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream5_IRQn);
  /* DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQn);

}
```

in the main function:

```
int main(void){
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  MX_TIM15_Init();
  MX_OPAMP2_Init();
  
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  set_sine(dac_data1, NUM_DAC_POINTS) //Set a max amplitude uniformly over number of points, dac_data is initialized as uint8_t dac_data1[NUM_DAC_POINTS];
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim15); //Start the timer for DAC DMA Transfer
  HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1);
  (HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2, (uint32_t *)dac_data1, NUM_DAC_POINTS, DAC_ALIGN_8B_R);
}
```

This setup does not work, but just by initialzing `dac_data1` as `const uint8_t` and predefining it, the DMA works.

Comment: DMA would be quite useless if it was unable to fetch data from RAM. There is probably some error in your configuration. You need to give more details.

Comment: Some STM32 parts have different memory banks, core-coupled-memory (CCM) is usable by the processor but not DMA.  Check the address against the reference manual to see which bank it corresponds to.

Comment: From the build analyzer, `dac_data1` is on RAM (0x2000002c). ITCMRAM, RAM_D1, RAM_D2 and RAM_D3 are all empty. In the reference manual (RM0468 for H723), I can't find any reference to "CCM," "core-coupled-memory," or "CCMRAM". Is there a datasheet or webpage dedicated to CCM for h723? All of the links I could find online are all from third-party sites and/or different target MCU's. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomV All RAMS **are** accesible by DMA in H7 family. It is a piece of false information. It has 3 DMA controllers and you need to chain two to access some memories. But it is doable - I did it myself when I familiarizing H7 family.

Comment: I said "some STM32 parts" not H7 specifically.  What I said is correct but not a direct answer the question which is why I made it a comment.  Still, it helped the OP find his own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Thanks to Tom V for the insight on the Different Memory Banks. In my case, `dac_data1` is placed on `RAM`, also known as `DTCMRAM` on the reference manual. `DTCMRAM` is not accessible to DMA but is chosen to be the default memory location for runtime operations on the H7. A modification in the linker files (In my case, both ..._FLASH.ld and ..._RAM.ld) were needed. I changed the .bss, .data and ._user_heap_stack memory location from `RAM` to `RAM_D1`. This was taken directly from: https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-DMA-is-not-working-on-STM32H7-devices

Comment: No problem!  You should mark the green tick next to your own answer if the question is now solved.